# How to check if a list of dates contains a certain month

Tags: python

I have a scraper that pulls a list of dates from a website. I want to check if any of the dates in the list are on December. The format for the dates is DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM. It makes sense for me to check if the list contains the string '.12.' to check for December but it does not seem to be working.

```
ret = []
for t in html_element:
    ret.append(t.text)
print(ret)

if '.12.' in ret:
    print('hello')
```

Comment: ret, is your array, you need to iterate through it and check for .12.

Comment: Can you provide some sample output?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including input data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ret is a list of arrays of the form "dd.mm.YYYY HH.MM"

```
print( any( '.12.' in i for i in ret) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ret` variable is a list and hence `if '.12.' in ret` will not work. You should do

```
for i in ret:
   if '.12.' in i:
      print('hello')
```